# prologで人工知能

Tags: prolog

prologで人工知能（エキスパートシステム等の推論システム）の作り方、その他の応用(帰納論理プログラミング等)を学べる論文やサイト、おすすめの本(入門書以外)はありますか？
自分で探した結果、入門書や入門サイトがたくさん出てきましたが、それらは一通り目を通しました。具体的には「prologの技芸」「prolog techniques」等の本、「amzi! inc」というサイトで基本を学びました。現在はより応用的な経験を積みたいと思い、自分で推論システムを構築したり帰納論理プログラミングを行いたいと思っています。そこで参考になるような、中級者以上向けの難易度が高い内容を扱っている本やサイトをお願いします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問は質問の意図がやや不明瞭なので、いくつか確認させてください。まず、ご自身で調べてみた結果どうだったでしょうか。「prolog 人工知能」で検索すればたくさんのウェブページが出てきますが、これらのページで満足できなかった理由を教えて頂けませんか？　次に、「人工知能」とは何でしょうか。この言葉は時代によって意味が大きく変わっている言葉として有名です。Daisuke さんは具体的にどのようなものを作ろうとなさっているのでしょうか？　Daisuke さんの解決したい課題が詳しく分かれば、答えやすくなるかと思います。お手数ですがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 他の回答者の方々へ、参考メタ質問です：[「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/19110)

Answer (score 2):

Prologによる知識表現については、中島秀之氏(札幌市立大学学長)の論文

[知識表現用言語としてのProlog/KR](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110002723866)　あたりから読み始めると良いと思います。

Prologは知識（推論のルール）を記述して、それに沿って論理を進めるシステムであって、CNNによる深層学習のような大量データからルールを学習するものとは全く異なるものです。

質問の「人工知能」が深層学習のようなものを想定しているのであれば、Prologとは相当距離があると思います。

Comment: 推論システムのつもりで人工知能と言っていました。抽象的で大変申し訳ないです。